# Are the IDs in XLF (XLIFF) files important in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, xliff

I'm wondering if the IDs on `trans-unit` tags are important in XLF files when using them with Symfony/PHP? Should they have be unique within a file? Across files? Does it matter what string/integer is used? I can't find documentation of what, if anything they're used for, including on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLIFF).

It's probably a more generic question, but I'm working with Symfony (PHP) at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Symfony, they don't matter. Symfony doesn't actually really support Xliff, it just knows how to extract 2 elements from the file and transform it into a key -> value array, as with all other formats.

However, if you're going to use translation tools (you probably are, otherwise you had choosen a simpler format), then you need to follow the [Xliff specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/v1.2/os/xliff-core.html#trans-unit):

> The required id attribute is used to uniquely identify the `<trans-unit>` within all `<trans-unit>` and `<bin-unit>` elements within the same `<file>`.
>
> ... (from id specs):
>
> [...] The value of the id element is determined by the tool creating the XLIFF document. [...]
>
> **Value description**: Text. Note that, while allowed, spaces are usually not used in identifiers.

Comment: What format would you recommend? It seems that Symfony's docs recommend using XLF: "The recommended option is to use xlf for translations." https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#translation-resource-file-names-and-locations

Comment: Just use Yaml :) I'm trying very hard to change the official recommendation and it seems like most core devs agree: https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5026

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably switch to YAML...have to make a final decision on that but your "argument" is pretty convincing :)

Answer (score 1):

I would have put this into a comment under Wouter J's answer if I had the required reputation, but since this is not the case here comes another answer.

The format you choose should work for both you and your translator. If you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer-assisted_translation#Some_notable_CAT_tools you will see that many translation tools have built-in support for XLIFF, whereas none supports YAML.
On the other hand some of these tools allow Regex-based parsing for input files, so you should probably discuss with your translator what format he would prefer to work with: putting together a set of Regex rules to handle YAML might work better for him than having to deal with poor XLIFF (and the XLIFF examples from Wouter J's link have some room for improvement).